# Delete all table data in a set [DB].[audit].[tables]

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

So, I have a database with around 100 audit tables and I want to empty them out preferably in 1 sql query. The database has 2 sets of tables [audit] and [dbo]. I'm not even sure what I should be calling these groups of tables so finding any kind of results from google is proving difficult.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find all tables with a certain schema name like:

```
select name from sys.tables where schema_name(schema_id) = 'audit'
```

With a cursor, you iterate over those tables, and empty them using [TRUNCATE TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260621(SQL.80).aspx):

```
use db
declare @query nvarchar(max)
declare @tablename nvarchar(max)
declare @curs cursor
set @curs = cursor for select name from sys.tables 
    where schema_name(schema_id) = 'audit'
open @curs
fetch next from @curs into @tablename
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 begin
 set @query = N'truncate table audit.' + @tablename
 exec sp_executesql @query
 fetch next from @curs into @tablename
 end
close @curs
deallocate @curs
```

If you want to delete the tables instead, use:

```
set @query = N'drop table audit.' + @tablename
```

Comment: You can print out all the sql statements instead of executing them and visually inspect them before you run them.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the sp_msforeachtable stored procedure.
It lets you perform a query on each user table in the current DB.

For example the following will truncate all user tables in your DB

```
Use YourDB
Exec sp_msforeachtable 'TRUNCATE TABLE ?'
```

And this will truncate all user tables in the specified db that belong to the audit schema.

```
Use YourDB
Exec sp_msforeachtable @command1 = '
    if (Select Object_Schema_name(object_id(''?''))) = ''dbo''
    Begin 
        TRUNCATE TABLE ?
        print ''truncated '' + ''?'' 
    End
    '
```

Also [Here](http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2009/04/8-common-uses-of-undocumented-stored.html) is a blog entry with some more uses for this stored procedure.